# Using DataPoints with @Before in Unit

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit

Is there a way in JUnit that I could replace my @Before method to @Theory so that it could use DataPoints. 
Actually I want the @Before method to be called with different values, a functionality that @Theory provides using Data points.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do that with parameterized tests?

See the example at https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests, and just replace @Test with @Before to set up different values in the @Before method.